# The largest element in magnitude of a Hermitian positive definite matrix is on the diagonal

Tags: linear-algebra

Anyone can help provide a proof for

> The largest element in magnitude of a Hermitian positive definite matrix is on the diagonal.

I found one related question [Why is the largest element of symmetric, positive semidefinite matrix on the diagonal?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1382940/why-is-the-largest-element-of-symmetric-positive-semidefinite-matrix-on-the-dia) whose answer proves a similar claim for symmetric positive definite matrix. However, I think the prove fails for a matrix with complex numbers, as the imaginary part also contributes to the magnitude.

Answer (score 5):

To repeat the Wikipedia article on [positive-definite matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive-definite_matrix#Further_properties):

Suppose the complex matrix $M$ is positive definite. The diagonal entries $m_{ii}$ are real and non-negative. As a consequence the trace, $tr(M) ≥ 0$. Furthermore, since every principal sub matrix (in particular, $2\times 2$) is positive definite, $${\displaystyle |m_{ij}|\leq {\sqrt {m_{ii}m_{jj}}}\leq {\frac {m_{ii}+m_{jj}}{2}}}$$
and thus
$${\displaystyle \max |m_{ij}|\leq \max |m_{ii}|}$$